# assertion error depending on the current folder?

Tags: matlab, assertion

> ---
>
> ```
>          Assertion detected at Wed Dec 16 14:27:14 2015
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Assertion failed: Forced Assertion at line 714 of file
>   ".\memmgr\mem32aligned.cpp".
>   Corrupted memory block found

Configuration:
  MATLAB Version:   7.5.0.342 (R2007b)

MATLAB License:   144193

Operating System: Microsoft Windows XP

Window System:    Version 5.1 (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)

Processor ID:     x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel

Virtual Machine:  Java 1.6.0 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM mixed mode

I am analyzing some .raw data with **matlab**.

The program runs fine when analyzing the file **FILE.raw**. But when the very same **FILE.raw** is in folder /dummyfolder.

I get the following error:

```
Stack Trace:
  [0] udd_mi.dll:_ouMakeRefsExternal(1, 0x014c6ac8, 0, 0x00ceb020) + 51 bytes
  [1] udd_mi.dll:public: virtual struct mxArray_tag * __thiscall UDInterfaceVectorMC::convertToMatlabArray(void const *)(0x12ae7000, 0xc7335f60, 0x12ae6360, 0x12a8d3f0) + 94 bytes
  [2] udd_mi.dll:bool __cdecl ouCallMethodWithErrorTrap(class UDMethodInfo *,struct mxArray_tag *,int,struct mxArray_tag * * const,int,struct mxArray_tag const * * const,class Exception * *)(0x123e6b40, 0x12ae3420, 1, 0x00ceb0d4) + 1016 bytes
  [3] udd_mi.dll:bool __cdecl ouCallMethod(struct mxArray_tag *,struct mxArray_tag *,int,struct mxArray_tag * * const,int,struct mxArray_tag const * * const)(0, 0x12ae3420, 1, 0x00ceb0d4) + 192 bytes
  [4] hg.dll:_hgFindobj(0x12aef020, 0x00ceb274, 4, 0x00ceb2d4) + 583 bytes
  [5] hgbuiltins.dll:_findobjWrapper(1, 0x00ceb274, 3, 0x00ceb2d4) + 991 bytes
  [6] m_dispatcher.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_builtin::dispatch_mf(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(1, 0x00ceb274, 3, 0x00ceb2d4) + 112 bytes
  [7] m_dispatcher.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_MATLAB_fn::dispatch_fh(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(1, 0x00ceb274, 3, 0x00ceb2d4) + 163 bytes
  [8] m_interpreter.dll:__catch$?inDispatchFromStack@@YAHHPBDHH@Z$0(199, 0x031921e0 "findobj", 1, 3) + 744 bytes
  [9] m_interpreter.dll:enum opcodes __cdecl inDispatchCall(char const *,int,int,int,int *,int *)(0x031921e0 "findobj", 199, 1, 3) + 156 bytes
  [10] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterp(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag volatile *,int *)(1, 2451, 66, 0) + 2614 bytes
  [11] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl protected_inInterp(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *,int *)(1, 2451, 49, 0) + 87 bytes
  [12] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterPcodeSJ(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *,int *)(1, 2451, 49, 0) + 274 bytes
  [13] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inExecuteMFunctionOrScript(class Mfh_mp *,bool)(0x12a99da0, 0x7c91e900, 0xc76fa4a4, 0xffffffff) + 916 bytes
  [14] m_interpreter.dll:void __cdecl inRunMfile(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,class Mfh_mp *,struct inWorkSpace_tag *)(0, 0x00ceba9c, 1, 0x00cebb2c) + 673 bytes
  [15] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(struct _mdUnknown_workspace *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0, 0x00ceba9c, 1) + 29 bytes
  [16] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0x00ceba9c, 1, 0x00cebb2c) + 28 bytes
  [17] m_dispatcher.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_file::dispatch_fh(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0x00ceba9c, 1, 0x00cebb2c) + 203 bytes
  [18] m_interpreter.dll:void __cdecl mdCallFunction(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,class Mfh_MATLAB_fn *)(0, 0x00ceba9c, 1, 0x00cebb2c) + 56 bytes
  [19] m_interpreter.dll:public: void __thiscall ResolverFunctionDesc::CallFunction(int,struct mxArray_tag * * const,int,struct mxArray_tag * * const)(0, 0x00ceba9c, 1, 0x00cebb2c) + 93 bytes
  [20] m_interpreter.dll:public: bool __thiscall Resolver::CallMFunction(int,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage *,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage *,int *)(0, 1, 0x1285d760, 0) + 1388 bytes
  [21] m_interpreter.dll:bool __cdecl inResolveMFunctionCall(struct _m_function_desc *,int,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage *,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage *,int *,enum inMarshalType *,int,class mpsTypeSequenceNlhs const *,struct mxArray_tag * (__cdecl*)(int))(0x13f098c8, 0, 1, 0x1285d760) + 195 bytes
  [22] m_interpreter.dll:private: bool __thiscall accelImpl::MFunctionCall(struct _accelOp * *)(0x00cec138, 0xc76fd258, 0x12bab540, 0x02e91560) + 179 bytes
  [23] m_interpreter.dll:public: enum jitReturnFlags __thiscall accelImpl::Exec(void)(0xc76fd2c0, 0x12bab540, 1, 0x00cec4ec) + 205 bytes
  [24] m_interpreter.dll:public: enum jitReturnFlags __thiscall accelCode::Call(enum inMarshalType *,int *)const (0x00cec23c, 0x00cec214, 0xc76fd10c, 0) + 128 bytes
  [25] m_interpreter.dll:public: static bool __cdecl inJit::ExecuteHotSegment(struct _inJitAccelInfo *,enum opcodes *,int *,int *)(0x00cec2e4, 0x00cec398, 0x00cec348, 0x00cec4ec) + 1898 bytes
  [26] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterp(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag volatile *,int *)(1, 0, 284, 0) + 338 bytes
  [27] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl protected_inInterp(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *,int *)(1, 0, 101, 0) + 87 bytes
  [28] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterPcodeSJ(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *,int *)(1, 0, 101, 0) + 274 bytes
  [29] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inExecuteMFunctionOrScript(class Mfh_mp *,bool)(0x0320a2e0, 0x79588701, 0xc76fd5f4, 0xffffffff) + 916 bytes
  [30] m_interpreter.dll:void __cdecl inRunMfile(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,class Mfh_mp *,struct inWorkSpace_tag *)(0, 0x00cec94c, 0, 0x00cec9dc) + 673 bytes
  [31] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(struct _mdUnknown_workspace *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0, 0x00cec94c, 0) + 29 bytes
  [32] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0x00cec94c, 0, 0x00cec9dc) + 28 bytes
  [33] m_dispatcher.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_file::dispatch_fh(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0x00cec94c, 0, 0x00cec9dc) + 203 bytes
  [34] m_interpreter.dll:void __cdecl mdCallFunction(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,class Mfh_MATLAB_fn *)(0, 0x00cec94c, 0, 0x00cec9dc) + 56 bytes
  [35] m_interpreter.dll:public: void __thiscall ResolverFunctionDesc::CallFunction(int,struct mxArray_tag * * const,int,struct mxArray_tag * * const)(0, 0x00cec94c, 0, 0x00cec9dc) + 93 bytes
  [36] m_interpreter.dll:public: bool __thiscall Resolver::CallMFunction(int,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage *,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage *,int *)(0, 1, 0x12857e20, 0) + 1388 bytes
  [37] m_interpreter.dll:bool __cdecl inResolveMFunctionCall(struct _m_function_desc *,int,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage *,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage *,int *,enum inMarshalType *,int,class mpsTypeSequenceNlhs const *,struct mxArray_tag * (__cdecl*)(int))(0x1251f1a0, 0, 1, 0x12857e20) + 195 bytes
  [38] m_interpreter.dll:private: bool __thiscall accelImpl::MFunctionCall(struct _accelOp * *)(0x00cecfe8, 0xc76fdce8, 0x015d56c0, 0x02e93c20) + 179 bytes
  [39] m_interpreter.dll:public: enum jitReturnFlags __thiscall accelImpl::Exec(void)(0xc76fc310, 0x015d56c0, 1, 0x00ced39c) + 205 bytes
  [40] m_interpreter.dll:public: enum jitReturnFlags __thiscall accelCode::Call(enum inMarshalType *,int *)const (0x00ced0ec, 0x00ced0c4, 0xc76fc25c, 0) + 128 bytes
  [41] m_interpreter.dll:public: static bool __cdecl inJit::ExecuteHotSegment(struct _inJitAccelInfo *,enum opcodes *,int *,int *)(0x00ced194, 0x00ced248, 0x00ced1f8, 0x00ced39c) + 1898 bytes
  [42] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterp(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag volatile *,int *)(1, 0, 31, 0) + 338 bytes
  [43] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl protected_inInterp(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *,int *)(1, 0, 18, 0) + 87 bytes
  [44] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterPcodeSJ(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *,int *)(1, 0, 18, 0) + 274 bytes
  [45] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inExecuteMFunctionOrScript(class Mfh_mp *,bool)(0x03209da0, 0x79588701, 0xc76fc604, 0xffffffff) + 916 bytes
  [46] m_interpreter.dll:void __cdecl inRunMfile(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,class Mfh_mp *,struct inWorkSpace_tag *)(0, 0x00ced7fc, 0, 0x00ced88c) + 673 bytes
  [47] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(struct _mdUnknown_workspace *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0, 0x00ced7fc, 0) + 29 bytes
  [48] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0x00ced7fc, 0, 0x00ced88c) + 28 bytes
  [49] m_dispatcher.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_file::dispatch_fh(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0x00ced7fc, 0, 0x00ced88c) + 203 bytes
  [50] m_interpreter.dll:void __cdecl mdCallFunction(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,class Mfh_MATLAB_fn *)(0, 0x00ced7fc, 0, 0x00ced88c) + 56 bytes
  [51] m_interpreter.dll:public: void __thiscall ResolverFunctionDesc::CallFunction(int,struct mxArray_tag * * const,int,struct mxArray_tag * * const)(0, 0x00ced7fc, 0, 0x00ced88c) + 93 bytes
  [52] m_interpreter.dll:public: bool __thiscall Resolver::CallMFunction(int,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage *,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage *,int *)(0, 1, 0x02fb4c60, 0) + 1388 bytes
  [53] m_interpreter.dll:bool __cdecl inResolveMFunctionCall(struct _m_function_desc *,int,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage *,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage *,int *,enum inMarshalType *,int,class mpsTypeSequenceNlhs const *,struct mxArray_tag * (__cdecl*)(int))(0x12431558, 0, 1, 0x02fb4c60) + 195 bytes
  [54] m_interpreter.dll:private: bool __thiscall accelImpl::MFunctionCall(struct _accelOp * *)(0x00cede98, 0xc76fcd38, 0x12d41a60, 0x02e9c230) + 179 bytes
  [55] m_interpreter.dll:public: enum jitReturnFlags __thiscall accelImpl::Exec(void)(0xc76fcda0, 0x12d41a60, 1, 0x00cee24c) + 205 bytes
  [56] m_interpreter.dll:public: enum jitReturnFlags __thiscall accelCode::Call(enum inMarshalType *,int *)const (0x00cedf9c, 0x00cedf74, 0xc76fccec, 0) + 128 bytes
  [57] m_interpreter.dll:public: static bool __cdecl inJit::ExecuteHotSegment(struct _inJitAccelInfo *,enum opcodes *,int *,int *)(0x00cee044, 0x00cee0f8, 0x00cee0a8, 0x00cee24c) + 1898 bytes
  [58] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterp(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag volatile *,int *)(1, 0, 39, 0) + 338 bytes
  [59] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl protected_inInterp(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *,int *)(1, 0, 17, 0) + 87 bytes
  [60] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterPcodeSJ(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *,int *)(1, 0, 17, 0) + 274 bytes
  [61] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inExecuteMFunctionOrScript(class Mfh_mp *,bool)(0x03209a20, 0x12b7fd01, 0xc76ff754, 0xffffffff) + 916 bytes
  [62] m_interpreter.dll:void __cdecl inRunMfile(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,class Mfh_mp *,struct inWorkSpace_tag *)(0, 0x00cee4c4, 0, 0x00cee524) + 673 bytes
  [63] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(struct _mdUnknown_workspace *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0, 0x00cee4c4, 0) + 29 bytes
  [64] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0x00cee4c4, 0, 0x00cee524) + 28 bytes
  [65] m_dispatcher.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_file::dispatch_fh(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0x00cee4c4, 0, 0x00cee524) + 203 bytes
  [66] m_interpreter.dll:__catch$?inDispatchFromStack@@YAHHPBDHH@Z$0(769, 0x015e6214 "mio_analyze_save", 0, 0) + 744 bytes
  [67] m_interpreter.dll:enum opcodes __cdecl inDispatchCall(char const *,int,int,int,int *,int *)(0x015e6214 "mio_analyze_save", 769, 0, 0) + 156 bytes
  [68] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterp(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag volatile *,int *)(2, 0, 0, 0) + 2739 bytes
  [69] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl protected_inInterp(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *,int *)(2, 0, 0, 0) + 87 bytes
  [70] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterPcodeSJ(enum inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *,int *)(2, 0, 0, 0) + 274 bytes
  [71] m_interpreter.dll:_inInterPcode(2, 0xc76ffbac, 0, 0x12b43320 "mio_analyze_save\n") + 162 bytes
  [72] m_interpreter.dll:enum inExecutionStatus __cdecl in_local_call_eval_function(int *,struct _pcodeheader *,int *,struct mxArray_tag * * const,enum inDebugCheck,bool)(0x00cef2bc, 0x00cef32c, 0x00cef358, 2) + 152 bytes
  [73] m_interpreter.dll:enum inExecutionStatus __cdecl inEvalStringWithIsVarFcn(struct _memory_context *,char const *,enum EvalType,int,struct mxArray_tag * * const,enum inDebugCheck,struct _pcodeheader *,int *,bool (__cdecl*)(void *,char const *),void *,bool)(0x7ac2177c, 0x12b43320 "mio_analyze_save\n", 0, 0) + 2454 bytes
  [74] m_interpreter.dll:enum inExecutionStatus __cdecl inEvalCmdWithLocalReturnandtype(char const *,int *,enum inDebugCheck,bool)(0x12b43320 "mio_analyze_save\n", 0, 2, 0) + 107 bytes
  [75] m_interpreter.dll:_inEvalCmdNoEnd(0x12b43320 "mio_analyze_save\n", 0, 0xc704ecaa, 0x7ab9e7f0) + 20 bytes
  [76] bridge.dll:enum inExecutionStatus __cdecl ThrowSignal(char const *)(0x12b43320 "mio_analyze_save\n", 0xc704ebe6, 0x014e4428, 0x014e43c8) + 77 bytes
  [77] bridge.dll:__catch$_mnParser$0(0xc7330b64, 0x014e43c8, 0x014e43c8, 0) + 292 bytes
  [78] mcr.dll:public: void __thiscall mcrInstance::mnParser(void)(0xc7330bba, 0x004043f0, 336710, 0) + 62 bytes
  [79] MATLAB.exe:0x00401414(4194304, 0, 336710, 10)
  [80] MATLAB.exe:0x00401733(0, 0, 0x7ffdb000, 0x8054b6ed)
  [81] kernel32.dll:0x7c817077(0x00401910, 0, 0x78746341, 32)
```

It seems to be a problem of that particular folder.

Note also that if I simply copy the **FILE.raw** in another folder, the program runs without error.

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on?

Comment: try remove `/dummyfolder` and making it anew.

Comment: I tried. It didn't work.

Comment: Could you paste the full stack trace or check if any 3rd party binaries are involved? What code do you run, any mex functions you wrote yourself?

Comment: there are mex functions wrote by the constructor of the scientific instrument producing the .raw files. never had this problem before though.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a bug in the mex functions you received. Without having the source code available, there is no way to get it fixed. Contact the author of the function.

In case someone experiences the error with a self-written or open source mex function, [some explanations are available here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103080-why-do-i-get-the-error-corrupted-memory-block-when-using-the-libpointer-function)